# mariadb testcontainer not exposed to localhost

Tags: java, mariadb, testcontainers

I have created the following mariadb testcontainer

```
@Container
private static final @NotNull MariaDBContainer<?> mariadb = getMariaDBTestContainer(network);

private static MariaDBContainer<?> getMariaDBTestContainer(Network network) {

    MariaDBContainer mariadb = new MariaDBContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mariadb").withTag("10.5.8"))
            .withDatabaseName("db")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("pw")
            .withInitScript("database.sql")
            .withNetwork(network)
            .withNetworkAliases("mariadb")
            .withExposedPorts(3306)
    
    ;
    mariadb.start();
    mariadb.setPortBindings(Collections.singletonList(mariadb.getMappedPort(3306) +":3306"));
    return mariadb;
}
```

I verified that

mariadb.gethost() == "localhost"
and
mariadb.getMappedPort(3306) == 3306

after loading the test container however, I can reach the mariadb shell from anothe container in the same network by using mariadb container id but not via localhost. This commmand gives me mariadb shell

`mariadb --host <MARIADBCONTAINER_NAME> --port 3306 --user user --password`

but this command
`mariadb --host localhost --port 3306 --user user --password`
says
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'localhost' (99)`

i wonder why localhost cannot connect to the mariadbshell

Comment: Localhost might be bound to the loopback address (in IP4 127.0.0.1) which is not meant to be routeable, i.e. only valid on the box on which it's running. You should bind it to the LAN IP address if you want to communicate between boxes on the same LAN

Comment: @g00se how do you bind a test container to a LAN IP address?

Comment: No idea - I don't use that software, but it looks like you're doing host configuration, in which case you need to change the way you do it

Comment: I would take the precaution of making sure my 'theory' is correct first, using, e.g. `netstat`

Comment: i donot do host configuration, i  have 2 test containers which cannot see eachother on localhost eventhough they are in same network ...

Comment: So what's this then? *.withHostConfig(new HostConfig()...*

Comment: hmm. good question :D i modified it and removed the hostconfig but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MariaDB container port `3306` will be mapped to a random free port on your host, also see [this section](https://java.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#exposing-container-ports-to-the-host) in the official Testcontainers docs regarding networking between host and container.

To access the port after the container has started, use the following methods:

```
// access port
mariadb.getFirstMappedPort();

// get full JDBC URL
mariadb.getJDBCUrl();
```

Since you are using the `MariaDBContainer` module, you don't need to use
`withExpostedPorts()`, it is already auto-configured.

Furthermore, I am unsure what you are trying to achieve here, you should remove this code:

```
mariadb.setPortBindings(Collections.singletonList(mariadb.getMappedPort(3306) +":3306"));
```

For networking between containers, please check [this part](https://java.testcontainers.org/features/networking/#advanced-networking) of the docs.